# The smallest positive real number -- or, a field plus $\{\epsilon\}$

Tags: field-theory

Suppose we want there to be a smallest positive real number $\epsilon$, so we create a new field $\mathbb{E}$ with the elements $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\epsilon\}$.

$\epsilon$ should be the *smallest*, so we say that if you divide it by anything, you just get $\epsilon$ back.

$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, ~~~\frac{\epsilon}{a} = \epsilon
$$

Then we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\epsilon}{2} &= \epsilon\\
\epsilon &= 2\epsilon\\
\end{aligned}
$$

and if we divide by $\epsilon$, we get $1 = 2$. So I guess we'll have to forbid dividing by $\epsilon$. At this point we smack ourselves on the forehead, realizing that

$$\epsilon = 0$$

**Starting over**, another way of making $\epsilon$ the "smallest" would be just to declare it indivisible. So we disallow dividing $\epsilon$ by anything. (I suppose this is equivalent to saying that we disallow multiplying it by anything $< 1$. **Is this consistent?**)

But we can still multiply it by things, so we have a bunch of other elements in $\mathbb{E}$ as well:

$$
\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\epsilon, 2\epsilon, 3\epsilon \dots \pi\epsilon, 2\pi\epsilon, 3\pi\epsilon \dots, \text{etc.}\}
$$

Now, we don't have a field anymore. What do we have? Can this construction be carried out in a consistent way?

Comment: Looks a bit like the ring of dual numbers. If $K$ is any field you can construct the commutative ring $K[\epsilon]$ with $\epsilon^2=0$ as the quotient of the polynomial ring: $K[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$. A dual number $a+b\epsilon$ is invertible in $K[\epsilon]$, iff $a\neq0$.

Comment: "But we can still multiply. . ." is **false** - what should $\epsilon \times{1\over 2}$ be? (You mention $\pi\epsilon$ - what is $\pi\epsilon-3\epsilon$?)

Comment: Perhaps you are interested to [Hyperreal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)...

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I attempted to disallow multiplying it by anything $< 1$, but it does seem that your example $\pi \epsilon - 3 \epsilon$ sinks that.

Comment: Hyperreal number or Surreal number.  Theoretically the surreal numbers are the largest ordered field.  I don't really know how they resolve your field issues.

Comment: THe answer is in <a href ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number" >here</a> somewhere but I don't know where.  1/$\epsilon$ = $\omega$; the largest number. which is sort of interesting.

Comment: @fleablood: Hyperreals are great! But I don't believe the hyperreals have a smallest (positive) element, do they? Rather, a whole family of them. As for the surreals, I have no idea -- do they?

Comment: According to the wikipedia pages both of them do. I'm not sure how that jibes with field axioms.  For a  > 1, e/a < e.  So I'm lost.  But it seems to be acceptable.  Read the pages.

Comment: @fleablood: Where do you get that from the hyperreals page? It references $dx^2$ being smaller than $dx$, so looks to me like there must be an infinitely decreasing sequence.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read it in the hyperreal pages.  But it's in the surreal numbers page.  But for the life of me I do not understand how the  ordered field axiom a<b c> 0 implies ac < bc can hold  I really don't.

Comment: @EliRose In all the nonstandard analysis systems I know of, there is no smallest infinitesimal. There *are* NSA systems with infinitesimals that provide fields in the usual sense, though.

Comment: @EliRose : As others have said, Nonstandard analysis provides you with plenty of examples. My favorite way of making infinitesimals rigorous is using [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis). At the price of giving up classical logic for intuitionistic logic you get that every real-valued function is smooth, reasoning with infinitesimals similar to what physicists do today and mathematicians of the pre 19th century did works, and weird statements like the Banach-Tarski theorem simply don't hold.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow division then your idea naturally leads to the Levi-Civita fields, which date from over a century ago and have been extensively studied.

If you don't allow division, one idea would be to take an infinitesimal hyperreal $\epsilon>0$ and work only with hyperinteger multiples thereof. Such objects are called "hyperfinite" and are used routinely in calculus and analysis in this approach.  For example, my favorite proof of the extreme value theorem passes via such a hyperfinite "grid"; see Keisler for example.

An integral, needless to say, is defined by taking such a partition into infinitely thin strips and adding them all up--and then passing to the *shadow*.

Comment: It seems a bit much to say that hyperfinite quantities are used "routinely in calculus and analysis". Rather, there is a subcommunity of these fields that uses them routinely.

Comment: @MarcPaul, thanks, corrected.